# Django inbuilt functions not working

Tags: django, function

I am trying to make a user login page in Django following the book "How to Tango with Django" (for the most part). My form appears on the template as it should but upon submission I get the following errors:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'save'

'function' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

The relevant part of my view function is as follows:

```
   if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
```

My model is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', 
    blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling it as a function.  You're using `user = user_form.save` but you want `user = user_form.save()` and if you don't want to commit it, `user = user_form.save(commit=False)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Those darn parentheses!